# Passar valor input para URL API

Tags: php, json

Passar valor do INPUT para URL API

Tenho uma conta em um sistema externo de IP's que tem API que passa pela URL.

Por exemplo, se eu quiser autorizar um IP, basta digitar no navegador...

```
https://MEUSITE.com/proxy/dashboard/api/ips/add/usuarioAPI/SenhaAPI/123.123.123.123
```

...que ele vai adicionar o iP 123... na base de dados. Pois, o usuario e senha já estão na URL.

Então eu preciso criar um formulário igual ao abaixo para informar esse IP e que ao enviar ele execute a URL.

Segue abaixo o formulário:

```
<form method="get" action="https://MEUSITE.com/proxy/dashboard/api/ips/add/usuarioAPI/SenhaAPI/{IP}">
    <p>Adicionar IP: <input type="text" name="IPadicionar"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></p>
</form>
```

Eu tentei da forma padrão, que era, colocar a variável no final da url - /?IPAdicionar - mas não deu certo. Pois, a url tem que ter apenas o IP no final e não pode ter `?` ou `=`.

Então, minha dúvida é como faço para, ao clicar em enviar, ele passe apenas o IP digitado no input para o final da URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa **consumir a API utilizando JS**, pois o HTML não vai modificar dados automaticamente depois que a página já foi impressa, e a URL da sua API não aceita query (?algo=123).

Para isso tem duas soluções, começando com a mais simples.

**1. utilize JS para modificar seu action, ao inserir dados no input:**

```
<form id="formAPI" method="get" action="">
    <p>Adicionar IP: <input type="text" id="ipAdd" onchange="ipChange(this)"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></p>
</form>
<script>
    function ipChange(elementoIp){
    let urlApi = 'https://MEUSITE.com/proxy/dashboard/api/ips/add/usuarioAPI/SenhaAPI/';
    let elementoForm = document.querySelector('#formAPI');
    elementoForm.action = urlApi + elementoIp.value;
    }
</script>
//Aqui removi o name do seu input para que não fosse adcionado ?campo=algo na URL
```

O atributo `onchange`no seu input faz com que a função seja executada quando o campo for modificado e perder o foco (ao clicar fora do campo, ou em outro elemento como o botão `Enviar`), nesse momento a função modifica o action do seu FORM.

Obs: `this` = elemento que acionou a função, nesse caso o input.

A segunda forma é mais recomendada, dessa forma a página não terá redirecionamento ao enviar a requisição:

**2. utilize JS para consumir a API diretamente:**

```
<div id="minhaAPI">
    <p>Adicionar IP: <input type="text" id="ipAdd"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" onclick="ipChange()" value="Enviar"></p>
</div>
<script>
    function ipChange(){
    let urlApi = 'https://MEUSITE.com/proxy/dashboard/api/ips/add/usuarioAPI/SenhaAPI/';
    let elementoIp = document.querySelector('#ipAdd');
    let urlAdd = urlApi + elementoIp.value;

    fetch(urlAdd).then(function(response) {
      if(response.ok) {
        alert('IP adicionado!');
      } else {
        alert('Houve um erro ao conectar ao servidor!');
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      alert('Houve um erro na requisição: ' + error.message);
    });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo retorno. Ele adiciona o IP perfeitamente porem retorna o erro ( erro na requisição:failed to fetch )

Comment: Se a URL da API está em seu domínio, verifique se seu host está configurado para permitir requisições JS e se o protocolo na URL (http / https) é igual na pagina do JS e na URL da API, confira também o código de resposta da requisição, pode usar o Inspetor / `DevTools` (tecla F12 ou control shift + i) do navegador, na aba Network para verificar. Caso a API não esteja em seu domínio verifique se é permitido requisições JS de outros domínios (`Cross Origin Resource Sharing`), caso não seja será necessário criar um PHP próprio que faça requisição com CURL por exemplo para ser chamado pelo seu JS.

Comment: Como opção ao JS Fetch, também é possível usar XMLHttpRequest:


Exmplo [https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp)


Detalhes: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Essas duas opções que você passou, ( Zimaldo Junior ) porem por se tratar de <script> se o usuario ver o codigo fonte da pagina, vai conseguir visualizar o usuario e senha da api que é passada na URL. teria alguma alternativa para ocultar?

Comment: Para ocultar essa informação você pode criar um script PHP para fazer a requisição principal via CURL, e no JS invés de chamar o endpoint da API diretamente, faça requisição para o seu PHP e envie o IP que será adicionado a lista de permissão.
Aqui você encontra bem explicado como usar CURL no PHP:
https://imasters.com.br/back-end/curl-com-php-para-apis-restfull